# virtualbox guest os cant use less cpu cores than host os

Tags: virtualbox, windows-server-2012

I use virtualbox version 4.3.2.0, the host os is windows 8.1 professional and the guest
os is windows server 2012.
the host cpu is AMD Athlon 64 x2 4000+ dual core processor with 2.1 GHz.
if I allocate 2 cpu cores to the guest everything is great.
if I allocate only 1 cpu core to guest then 2 seconds after the windows logo is shown
I get a blue screen which says 'your pc into a problem and needs to restart' and then guest os restarts.
I tried to enable PAE/NX on the guest os cpu settings but it didn't helped.

Thanks, Ido

Comment: How many cores were assigned when you installed the guest?

Comment: when I installed the guest I had the same problem, so I was 'forced'
to install it with 2 cores. if I recall right I never had this problem with virtual pc.